# AccordionPane nested inside a Repeater?

Tags: .net, repeater, accordion

i am trying to create a repeater that will create multiple Accordion Panes within an accordion controller, but it looks like the two cannot be nested. is there a workaround for this?

this is what i'm trying to do:

```
<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" >
    <Panes>
      <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rpPanes">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
             <Header>header from db here</Header>
             <Content>content from DB here </Content>
           </asp:AccordionPane>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </Repeater>
    </Panes>
</asp:Accordion>
```

the number of accordion panes needs to be dynamic, as it comes from the database, and someone can always add or remove one (within the DB itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Istead of using repeater for repeating accordionpanes, just use repeater to repeat Accordions. You will have an seperate Accordion for each pane. This will result up with independent accordions.